# How to use Auto filter criteria from a cell reference on another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

Need help in using vba to auto filter columns in a workbook but the filter criteria is in a cell reference on another workbook. To Start, i have 2 workbooks, the first is the report template where the macro is entered and the other is the data file that needs to be filtered.

Comment: I have created the vba coding for this question i posted. if you will open the post, i will submit my code as answer to help those who are searching for the same situation i encountered.

Comment: Without explicitly opening the other workbook?

Comment: i actually needed to open both workbooks since after filtering, i am copying the filtered data from the data file onto the report template

Comment: Understood. Do you recommend that i delete this post then?

Comment: That;s not necessary, it has been already closed. But did you try my solution? I'm curious because I didn't find another way without opening the other WB explicitly, without using this big old `ExecuteExcel4Macro` :P

Answer (score 2):

You can reference reference cells in the (closed) template workbook in your `Autofilter` VBA statement. `ExecuteExcel4Macro` is of help here, permitting to evaluate a reference to another, closed workbook the same way it would be typed in a formula.

For example, to autofilter a range by cell `B5` of the control sheet in the report template:

```
myRange.AutoFilter 1, ExecuteExcel4Macro("'C:\myPath\myfolder\[Report.xltx]control'!R5C2")
```

Notice that `ExecuteExcel4Macro` requires *RC-style* addresses, so use `R5C2` for `B5`, `R5C3` for `C5` and `R5C4` for `D5`...